# Getting error while parsing fault soap message :org.w3c.dom.DOMException: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, axis, stub

I am getting the error

> org.w3c.dom.DOMException: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a
>   different document than the one that created it.

while parsing the soap fault response. I am able to parse success soap message.

I have generated the stub class from wsdl using axis 1.4. Please help

Comment: Please add the soap message.

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Please find the fault response:
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>
      <env:Fault xmlns:fault="http://msmi.fsecure.com/MSMI">
         <faultcode>fault:MSMI_030</faultcode>
         <faultstring/>
         <detail>Username is not available.</detail>
      </env:Fault>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>

Comment: @Sindhuja, please show your XML parser code.

Comment: Hi Ye win, I am using code generated by axis 1.4 from wsdl to parse xml